# AWS CLI v2 ignoring --profile when AWS_PROFILE set

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have my `~/.aws/credentials` file with a predefined profile (`foo`) in it:

```
[foo]
aws_access_key_id = <MY_KEY_ID>
aws_secret_access_key = <MY_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY>
```

I have my `AWS_PROFILE` set to a different value (`bar`):

```
$ echo $AWS_PROFILE
bar
```

Now when I go to run an `aws` command I specify the profile using the `--profile` option, but AWS CLI is still trying to use the profile specified as `AWS_PROFILE`:

```
$ aws ecr get-login-password --region=us-west-1 --profile=foo
The config profile (bar) could not be found
```

I'm pretty sure the `--profile` parameter is supposed to override the env var, so can anyone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: Further info

Adding an entry to my `config` file doesn't fix the problem:

```
[profile foo]
region = us-east-1
source_profile = foo
```

Also, `--profile` works perfectly if the `AWS_PROFILE` env var is unset, even without the entry in the `config` file:

```
$ unset AWS_PROFILE
$ aws ecr get-login-password --region=us-west-1 --profile=foo
eyJwY...1fQ==
```

Comment: Check out this issue. https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/5016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is because `AWS_PROFILE` is set to an invalid value, and apparently this causes it to be prioritised above the `--profile` option. So:

```
$ unset AWS_PROFILE
$ aws configure list-profiles
default
user1
$ export AWS_PROFILE=user1
$ aws configure list-profiles --profile=default
default
user1
$ export AWS_PROFILE=user2
$ aws configure list-profiles --profile=default --debug

The config profile (user2) could not be found
```

This seems like a bug so I've opened a ticket [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/5333).

The current workaround I'm using is to set `AWS_PROFILE` at the start of the command:

```
AWS_PROFILE=foo aws ecr get-login-password --region=us-west-1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [.aws/config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html#cli-configure-files-settings) is missing or does not have profile for `foo`.
Example content could be as follows:

**.aws/config**

```
[profile foo]
region = us-east-1
```

Comment: Except that when I unset `AWS_PROFILE` it works perfectly.

Comment: @LomaxOnTheRun Do you have set it up in config file?

Comment: I don't, but with the env var unset it does work. I would like to avoid setting a config for it if I can avoid it.

Comment: @LomaxOnTheRun I'm not sure if can avoid it. If you can I would try with it, and see if it helps.

Comment: So even adding a profile in my config file doesn't seem to fix this (I'll update the question to reflect this).

Comment: @LomaxOnTheRun I tried to replicate the issue, but in my tests `--profile` correctly overwrites the `AWS_PROFILE` env variable. Also why do you use `source_profile = foo`? Isn't it for roles only?

Comment: I assumed `source_profile` linked to the named profile in credentials, but I could be way wrong about that. I've added an answer below that explains what's happening, at least on my machine.